# dojo 1.8 data grid populated from query not rendering

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I want to create datagrid which is populated based on the query made to server

the code i have is

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!", "dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/data/ObjectStore"],
        function (DataGrid, ObjectStore, dom) {

            var formQuery;
            require(["dojo/dom-form"], function (domForm) {
                formQuery = domForm.toQuery("form-filter");
            });

            var query = url + '?' + formQuery;
            console.log(query);

            var myStore;
            require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"], function (JsonRest) {
                myStore = new JsonRest({target: query});
            });


            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: dataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),
                structure: [
                    {name: "ID", field: "id", width: "25%"},
                    {name: "Task-predmet", field: "subject", width: "25%"},
                    {name: "Dodavatel", field: "contractorCompany", width: "10%"},
                    {name: "Stav", field: "status", width: "10%"},
                    {name: "Termin", field: "deadline", width: "10%"},
                    {name: "Vytvorene", field: "created", width: "10%"}
                ]
            }, "result-table-contractor-tasks-filter"); // make sure you have a target HTML element with this id
            grid.startup();
```

the query is 
http://localhost:8080/path?deadlineFrom=2015-11-15&deadlineTill=2016-11-15&createdFrom=2015-11-15&createdTill=2016-11-15

and it returns this

{"code":200,"status":"success","data":[{"id":1,"contractorCompany":"Best","status":"OTV","deadline":"Nov 4, 2016","subject":"","created":"Nov 3, 2016 1:11:22 PM"},{"id":3,"contractorCompany":"Best","status":"OTV","deadline":"Nov 14, 2016","subject":"a","created":"Nov 14, 2016 2:37:15 PM"}]}

but the datagrid is not rendering and i have no idea why. can you please help me? i'm using dojo 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dojox modules are experimental, and the grid is [deprecated](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/index.html#dojox-grid-index), might I recommend using SitePen's current [dgrid](http://dgrid.io/)? It is being actively developed, and has an accompanying library [dstore](http://dstorejs.io/) that includes a '[Request](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Stores.md#RequestMemory)' data store which is made for exactly this purpose.

Otherwise, if you're still interested in using the dojox/DataGrid, check out this article: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/11/21/effective-use-of-jsonreststore-referencing-lazy-loading-and-more/